# Unable to receive an email alert after making the auditing and thread detection feature on azure for sql server database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have enable the auditing and thread detection feature on azure for  database and also setup the email for same but not getting and email after making the sql injection attack.

Comment: Please review all the steps needed to configure Threat Detection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-threat-detection

Answer (score 0):

Please use [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-sql-security-sample) demo application to generate alerts from the Audit and Threat Detection feature.

Let me know if you still do not receive the alerts on your email mailbox. Please examine your junk mail also.